# mysql : How to obtain the list of product id's with two different conditions?

Tags: mysql

How to obtain the list of product id's which has size small and color green?

I have a table as

```
prodid | heading  |  description 

20    |   color    |   green

20    |   size     |    s

21    |   size     |    s

22    |  size     |    s
```

My query:

```
select prodid from tablename 
where heading in('color','size') and description in ('green','s');
```

but required output is "the list of prodid containing size small and green color".

```
prodid | heading  |  description 

20    |   color   |  green

20    |   size    |   s
```

Can any one please help me to write a query to obtain the above output.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need both color and size rows of the product to impose all the conditions, join the table to itself:

```
select t1.prodid
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.prodid = t1.prodid
where t1.heading = 'color' and t1.description = 'green'
and   t2.heading = 'size'  and t2.description = '5'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the query using nested 'and' and 'or's:

```
select prodid from tablename where (heading = 'color' and description = 'green') or (heading = 'size' and description = 's');
```

Comment: That is not what he is asking... he wants **both** conditions to be satisfied on the same prodid ;)

Comment: Ahh, I see. But his sample output is not actually what he wants... the 'correct' answer will give one row per prodid.

Comment: Yes... his result set is not absolutely clear... I agree

Comment: basically  i am working on a filter. the table contains the different attributes such as color,size,brand under a heading column name and there respective description such as green,s,brandname etc for each product id. i want to obtain the list of product id which has colour = green and size = s. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
select prodid from tablename 
  where heading = 'color' 
  and description = 'green' 
  and prodid in (select prodid from tablename 
         where heading = 'size' 
         and description = 's');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this:

```
SELECT prodid
FROM mytable a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT prodid
  FROM mytable b
  WHERE b.prodid=a.prodid AND b.heading='size' AND b.description='small'
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT prodid
  FROM mytable c
  WHERE c.prodid=a.prodid AND c.heading='color' AND c.description='green'
)
```

Even though it uses the table 3 times, I find it more readable and extensible.

If performance is an issue, it can be done by using the table only twice, like Bohemian suggested. But first make sure you have an index on (prodid,heading,description).